# Trying to determine if a movement vector is CW or CCW around a point

Tags: ios, touch, unity-game-engine

I'm writing some Touch input code for an iOS device and need to determine whether the movement of a swipe is clockwise or counterclockwise relative to the center of the screen.

Using the `position` and `deltaPosition` of the touch, I can calculate an angle between vectors from the center of the screen to those points using the dot product but that doesn't give me a *signed* angle to decide whether it's CW or not.

How can I tell which direction around the center the swipe has moved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let *A* denote the swipe vector, and *B* the vector from the start of the swipe to the center of the screen. You can then calculate the *determinant* of the components of *A* and *B*:

```
| A.x A.y |
| B.x B.y |

= A.x * B.y - B.x * A.y
```

The sign of the determinant will tell you whether *B* points to the right side or to the left side of *A*.

As @Jeremy W. Sherman correctly notes, which sign corresponds to which direction depends on how the coordinate system of the screen is laid out. If the *x* axis runs to the right and the *y* axis runs downward, positive means CW and negative means CCW (if I got the mental math right). Zero always means movement directly towards or directly away from the center.

Comment: …with the caveat that whether positive sign indicates CW or CCW depends on whether your y-axis increases going up the screen or going down the screen. x-axis direction of increase also matters, but it is less likely to be a problem on iOS than whether your origin is the top-left corner or bottom-left corner of the screen.